# How to open socket on a specific IP

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to create a simple server program through C but I don't want it to use my current IP, rather I want to provide a specific IP. But things are not working.

As the very first step to provide a specific IP, I removed the following statement from the code:
[NOTE]: Here, 'hints' is an object of `struct addrinfo`

```
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
```

That's because it automatically fills up our IP, not allowing us to provide a specific IP.

Then I tried to use `inet_pton()` to provide a specific IP to `sin_addr` (member of `sockaddr_in` structure) using the statement:

```
inet_pton(AF_INET , host_to_connect  , &(((struct sockaddr_in *)hints.ai_addr)->sin_addr));
```

Here, 'host_to_connect' is the string containing desired IP address in dotted decimal format(eg. char *host_to_connect = "192.168.22.23")

Since there is no member named `sin_addr` in `sockaddr` structure, I typecasted it into `sockaddr_in` structure and then accessed `sin_addr`.

Here is the actual code in which I am working on:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc , char **argv)
{
    char *host_to_connect = argv[1];
    char *port = argv[2];
    struct addrinfo hints , *server_info;

    memset(&hints , 0 , sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    inet_pton(AF_INET , host_to_connect  , &(((struct sockaddr_in *)hints.ai_addr)->sin_addr)); 

        //hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    int status;
    if((status = getaddrinfo(NULL , port , &hints, &server_info)) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr , "Error in getaddrinfo(): %s\n" , gai_strerror(status));
        return 2;
    }

    //creating a socket
    int socketfd;
    if((socketfd = socket(server_info->ai_family , server_info->ai_socktype , server_info->ai_protocol)) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr , "Error in socket() : %s\n " , gai_strerror(socketfd));
        return 2;
    }

    //binding port to socket
    int bind_status;
    if((bind_status = bind(socketfd , server_info->ai_addr , server_info->ai_addrlen)) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr , "Error in bind() : %s\n " , gai_strerror(bind_status));
        return 2;
    }

    //listining on the socket
    int listen_status;
    if((listen_status = listen(socketfd , 5)) == -1 )
    {
        fprintf(stderr , "Error in listen() : %s\n " , gai_strerror(listen_status));
        return 2;
    }

    //accepting connections
    int client_fd;
    struct sockaddr_storage client_info;
    socklen_t address_length = sizeof(client_info);
    if((client_fd = accept(socketfd , (struct sockaddr *)&client_info , &address_length)) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr , "Error in accept() : %s\n " , gai_strerror(client_fd));
        return 2;
    }

    //sending message to client
    char *message = "\n\nYou are successfully connected to the server!\n\n";
    int bytes_sent;
    bytes_sent = send(client_fd , message , strlen(message) , 0);
    printf("\nBytes sent: %d\n" , bytes_sent);

    close(socketfd);
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting it to work good but when I run it providing it necessary arguments like:

```
gcc server.c -o ./server
./server "192.168.22.23" "8989"
```

I am getting **Segmentation Fault** as output.

When I try to debug it using GNU debugger, It turns out that there is something wrong with the `inet_pton()` used in the code but I am not able to figure it out.

I will be glad if someone can clear things up!

Comment: Is `192.168.22.23` an IP for any of the interface on your machine?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I didn't thought about that. I just provided any random private IP address. Is it invalid?

Comment: That is not how network works. Your IP stack won't pick up packets not meant for your machine. So your application will never get them.

Comment: Ok! IP aside, Is my code right if we consider IP to be valid? I mean, Did I used the inet_pton() in right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing `getaddrinfo()` and `gai_strerror()`.

You are not supposed to populate `hints.ai_addr` at all. Only a few fields are valid for use in `hints` and `ai_addr` is not one of them:

> The *hints* argument points to an *addrinfo* structure that specifies criteria for selecting the socket address structures returned in the list pointed to by res. **If *hints* is not NULL it points to an *addrinfo* structure whose *ai_family*, *ai_socktype*, and *ai_protocol* specify criteria that limit the set of socket addresses returned by `getaddrinfo()`... All the other fields in the structure pointed to by *hints* must contain either 0 or a NULL pointer, as appropriate.**

To pass an IP as input to `getaddrinfo()`, you need to pass it in the `node` parameter instead, and specify the `AI_NUMERICHOST` flag in the `hints` parameter:

> *node* specifies either **a numerical network address (for IPv4, numbers-and-dots notation as supported by inet_aton(3); for IPv6, hexadecimal string format as supported by inet_pton(3))**, or a network hostname, whose network addresses are looked up and resolved. **If *hints.ai_flags* contains the `AI_NUMERICHOST` flag, then *node* must be a numerical network address.** The `AI_NUMERICHOST` flag suppresses any potentially lengthy network host address lookups.

Upon success, you can then use the `sockaddr*` provided by `server_info->ai_addr` in a call to `bind()`.

And call `gai_strerror()` only when `getaddrinfo()` fails. It is not valid to call when any other functions fail. Use `perror()` for them.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc , char **argv)
{
    // Validate the parameters
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("usage: %s <ip> <port>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    struct addrinfo hints, *server_info;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST; //AI_PASSIVE;

    int status = getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &hints, &server_info);
    if (status != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in getaddrinfo(): %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        return 2;
    }

    //creating a socket
    int socketfd = socket(server_info->ai_family, server_info->ai_socktype, server_info->ai_protocol);
    if (socketfd == -1)
    {
        perror("Error in socket()");
        freeaddrinfo(server_info);
        return 2;
    }

    //binding port to socket
    status = bind(socketfd, server_info->ai_addr, server_info->ai_addrlen);
    if (status == -1)
    {
        perror("Error in bind()");
        close(socketfd);
        freeaddrinfo(server_info);
        return 2;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(server_info);

    //listening on the socket
    status = listen(socketfd, 5);
    if (status == -1)
    {
        perror("Error in listen()");
        close(socketfd);
        return 2;
    }

    //accepting connections
    struct sockaddr_storage client_info;
    socklen_t address_length = sizeof(client_info);
    int client_fd = accept(socketfd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_info, &address_length);
    if (client_fd == -1)
    {
        perror("Error in accept()");
        close(socketfd);
        return 2;
    }

    //sending message to client
    char *message = "\n\nYou are successfully connected to the server!\n\n";
    int bytes_sent, bytes_to_send = strlen(message);
    do
    {
        bytes_sent = send(client_fd, message, bytes_to_send, 0);
        if (bytes_sent == -1)
        {
            perror("Error in send()");
            close(client_fd);
            close(socketfd);
            return 2;
        }
        printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", bytes_sent);
        message += bytes_sent;
        bytes_to_send -= bytes_sent;
    }
    while (bytes_to_send > 0);

    close(client_fd);
    close(socketfd);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're crashing is because you're trying to dereference a NULL pointer.

`hints.ai_addr` has the value NULL after your memset, but you try to drerefrence it with 
the expression `&(((struct sockaddr_in *)hints.ai_addr)->sin_addr))` when you call `inet_pton`.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in this case manifests as a crash.

Even if you fix that, you shouldn't be putting values into `hints.ai_addr`.  When passing a non-NULL value to `hints`, the structure can only contain values for the `ai_family`, `ai_socktype`, or `ai_protocol` fields.  The rest must be 0 or NULL.

For what you're doing, you're better off skipping the use of `getaddrinfo` and populating a `struct sockaddr_in` directly to pass to `bind`.  Also, `gai_strerror` is only used for getting error strings for `getaddrinfo`.  For other socket functions, use `strerror` or `perror`:

```
struct sockaddr_in sin;
memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));

sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
if  (!inet_pton(AF_INET, host_to_connect, &sin_sin_addr)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "invalid address\n");
    return 2;
}
sin.sin_port = htons((uint16_t)atoi(argv[2])); 

//creating a socket
int socketfd;
if((socketfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
{
    perror("Error in socket()");
    return 2;
}

//binding port to socket
int bind_status;
if((bind_status = bind(socketfd, (struct sockaddr *)&sin , sizeof(sin))) == -1)
{
    perror("Error in bind()");
    return 2;
}
```

Also, you can only bind to an IP address that is present on your system.  If you have more than one network interface, you can use this to listen on just one of them as opposed to all if you were to bind to 0.0.0.0.

Comment: "Also, you can only bind to an IP address that is present on your system" AIUI there is a socket option "freebind" which lets you override that check.

Comment: @dbush Thanks for the informative answer. Is using addrinfo structure a good practice? or should I rather use sockaddr structure and manually set things up?

Comment: @xscorp7 You would use `getaddrinfo` if you need to look up either a host or port by name, or if you might be using either IPv4 or IPv6.  If you're just working with numerical addresses and ports in IPv4, then just set up the `sockaddr_in` yourself.

Comment: "*you're better off skipping the use of `getaddrinfo` and populating a `struct sockaddr_in` directly to pass to `bind`*" - not necessarily. It is just as easy to keep using `getaddrinfo()`, just pass the IP string in the 1st parameter, and use the `AI_NUMERICHOST` flag in `hints`